Bugged Start and end Time in Jmeter report format?
For the last couple of days I've noticed a change in the display of the start and end time of tests in the Jmeter report.
It used to be normal like this:
normal display

but now it looks like that:
bugged display

I didn't change anything to any properties file.

If you haven't changed any properties then .jtl results file format has changed.
However to be absolutely sure I would re-install clean latest version of JMeter and re-generate the dashboard again.

The buged report is generated through Jenkins, I copied the jtl and regenerated the report on my own computer and the report is just fine.
